# Centering a span12 div in a container in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I have been through a number of similar questions, and tried to adapt the solutions to my case, but haven't had success in doing so.

I am trying to implement something of a reader, so I have a reading pane which I want to center on my page. I want to limit the size of the pane so that the user is no reading lines spanning the full width of a large browser window, but I also want to have that pane centered in the window. Above the pane I have a header which spans the full width of the page.

Originally I tried to use "span8 offset2" for the reading pane, but as the size of the window is reduced, I want the margins to disappear before the pane shrinks, and using this setup, the reading pane shrinks unnecessarily, squeezing content, as the window is made thinner.

I get the correct behavior just using "span12" with "max-width: 700px" set, in terms of the reading pane shrinking as I want it to, but I cannot get the div to center on the page.

Here is what I have that I'm working with:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span12 reading-pane">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="nav">
            <div class="span6 offset3">
              Main Navigation
            </div>
            <div class="span2 offset1">
              Nav2
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span12">
            <div class="body-text">
              Text Area
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The style for the reading-pane is as follows:

```
.reading-pane {
  border: solid;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-width: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  min-height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  max-width: 700px;
}
```

I have tried adding the following to the .reading-pane style (individually):

```
float: none;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

```
float: none;
margin: 0 auto;
```

I've also tried centering text in the container which centers my header text, but not the reading-pane.

So how do I get the span12 div to center on the page?

Comment: span12 is 100% width...what do you plan on centering exactly?

Comment: Like I said in my post, I'm wanting to center this reading pane, but I'm only wanting the pane to re-size when the page is reduced below the max-width (700px) I have set. If I size my reading pane by using a span/offset, then the pane is re-sized before the margins are consumed as the page is made smaller.

Comment: Any luck fixing this issue?

Comment: Not yet, no. I tried what you had in your comment below and was messing with some different things I've seen elsewhere as well. I also tried using span10 instead of span12, but unless I nest the span10 in a span12, I can't get it to center still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming since you're using `row-fluid` that you're using bootstrap 2.0.  Bootstrap 3.0 handles responsive grids a bit more cleanly, so if you can I'd recommend using 3.0.

Then move your max-width to the container:

```
.container {
    max-width: 700px;
}
```

Note that 700 includes the gutters so you may want to use 730.

Or better than using max-width, you can customize (http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) your twitter bootstrap download and define your own widths there if 700 is critical to you.  And you can then also remove the larger @media queries then.

There's a few other tweaks to how grids are done on 3.0, which I included in this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/PQM34/2/

Comment: Upgrading to Bootstrap 3.0 allowed me to solve this pretty easily. Instead of specifying a specific max-width on the container though, I just stuck with their defaults and for each of the screen sizes, selected the number of columns that will give me close to the size I want. This turned out to work very well!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to gauge without an example of your code and Bootstrap's source...
Note, it sounds like your using the framework incorrectly though. Why not just use span10, span8, etc. and center that?

In order to center divs, using `margin:0 auto` a fixed width is required (%, px, em, etc.).

Try adding this css to `.reading-pane`:

```
position:relative;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 700px;
float:none!important;
```